# Can I create a custom Front end and use Survey Monkey APIs as Backend?

Tags: api, surveymonkey

Can I use SurveyMonkey APIs with a custom Front end for my website? Example - I create a page add questions and the make a API call to add question to the survey. Send the link to a user and fetch the survey to display on the page and submit the response via API call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure your exact question, but the API docs are [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/) which can explain how to do all the things you want to do.

Creating surveys [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys)

```
POST /v3/surveys
```

Creating pages [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-pages)

```
POST /v3/surveys/{survey_id}/pages/
```

Creating questions [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#surveys-id-pages-id-questions)

```
POST /v3/surveys/{survey_id}/pages/{page_id}/questions
```

Creating responses [here](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#collectors-id-responses)

```
POST /v3/collectors/{collector_id}/responses
```

Hopefully that helps you get started.